# CoreData: error: batched fetch request asked to fetch 1 objects but received 2 objects

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchrequest, nsmanagedobjectid

I use two persistent stores: first is read-only for default (built-in) app's data, second is read-write for user data. The issue occurs once user add any data in second store. In this case during execution of *performFetch:* method of *NSFetchedResultsController* I see the following message in debug console:

```
CoreData: error:  batched fetch request asked to fetch 1 objects but
received 2 objects as (
    "entity: Product; id: 0xd000000000340002 <x-coredata://A570FA00-5B60-4C21-A9B1-8A49C2AAC58B/Product/p13> ; data: <fault>)",
    "entity: Product; id: 0xd000000000340004 <x-coredata://84F31C0F-844D-44DD-BB2F-CC766BED8331/Product/p13> ; data: <fault>)"
)
```

It's clear for me that CoreData interprets the situation as error because last parts of Managed ObjectIDs are the same:

```
Product/p13
```

For some reason CoreData doesn't take in account that these objects are from different stores: *A570FA00-5B60-4C21-A9B1-8A49C2AAC58B* and *84F31C0F-844D-44DD-BB2F-CC766BED8331* correspondingly.

Except error message in console everything works correctly. But I would prefer not to see it. Does anybody have an idea of how to resolve such a different stores ObjectID's collision?

Comment: Do you need the fetch to search in both stores?  If not then you could try using the `affectedStores` property of the fetch request for the FRC.

Comment: Thank you for recommendation, but yes, I need to fetch data from both stores.

Comment: Are you using `fetchBatchSize` for the fetch?  I believe in that case the FRC fetches all the objectIDs at first, then uses a subset of them to select a batch.  Have you tried enabling SQLDebug to see better what's going on?

Comment: Yes, I use fetchBatchSize for the sake of optimum memory usage. And you're right: as it turned out batching caused the error. SQLDebug doesn't show anything special. So it's obviously CoreData framework's error. 
More likely I will stop using fetchBatchSize in my particular case preferring clean debug console to optimization.